# Need suggestions, on getting Data from inputs to use in Ruby/Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im need some direction on how to properly use forms for ruby on rails.

I need to use the values from the below input to then use with some ruby.

```
<%= form_tag do %>
  Form contents
<% end %>
```

I now need to take the value from this input and use in the following

```
value = gets
puts value
```

All in all i just need to know the simplest way to input a value and use it within a ruby expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly put some input tags such as `text_field_tag` in your form helper

Then call the values in the controller as `params`

For example

```
<%= text_field_tag :name_and_surname %>
```

in your view ( in the form tag ) and

```
@name_and_surname = params[:name_and_surname]
```

in your controller